# Is it possible to share images from my ios app with instagram ?

Tags: ios, instagram

Is it possible to share images from my ios app with instagram without installing instagram app on the device ?

I also referred this link : `http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/`

I tried this code :

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

But I want to upload an image without installing instagram App on my device. Any suggestions and ideas on how this can be achieved if its possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload image without installing instagram in you device. It is not possible.